# How to specifically run a shell builtin command

Tags: bash, alias, shell-builtin

Consider a situation that I run these commands in my current shell or I put them inside `.bashrc`:

```
alias source='echo hi'
alias .='echo hi'
alias unalias='echo hi'
```

Or `function source(){ echo hi; }`, etc.

In case of binary commands we can use absolute path like: `/bin/ls`, however how can I specifically run any of these shell built-in commands inside my current shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bash has the command `builtin` for that:

```
builtin: builtin [shell-builtin [arg ...]]
Execute shell builtins.

Execute SHELL-BUILTIN with arguments ARGs without performing command
lookup.
```

E.g.

```
$ cat > hello.sh
echo hello
$ source() { echo x ; }
$ source hello.sh
x
$ builtin source hello.sh
hello
```

Nothing prevents you from overriding `builtin`, however.

Another way to work around aliases (but not functions) is to quote (part of) the word:

```
$ alias source="echo x"
$ source hello.sh 
x hello.sh
$ \source hello.sh
hello
```

Comment: Any workaround for functions? `function .(){ echo hi; }` ; `function builtin(){ echo hi; }` If I run `\builtin` It gives me `hi`.

Comment: @Ravexina, I think the choices are either `unset -f builtin` or to not override `builtin` in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

Aliases can always be bypassed by quoting any part of the command name, e.g. `\source` or `'source'` or `''source` or … (unless you've defined aliases for those as well which `zsh`, but not other shells, allows).

Functions can be bypassed with the `command` prefix (e.g. `command source`) in any POSIX shell. In bash or zsh you can use `builtin` instead of `command` to force the use of a builtin (`command` falls back to a `PATH` lookup if there's no builtin by that name, and in zsh (except when emulating other shells), `command` skips builtins altogether). You can unset a function with e.g. `unset -f source`.

If you've overridden or disabled all of `builtin`, `command` and `unset`, you may need to abandon the idea of restoring this shell instance to a reasonable state.

Comment: +1 Thanks, is there any way to disallow overwriting a function like `command` ?

Comment: @Ravexina Not in any of the usual shells, no.