# Turn off one flag of command and infinite recursion

Tags: zsh, alias, function

Since it overwrites my history when used in multiple terminals, I want to turn off the functionality `fc -W`. Unfortunately I have a habit of typing it often.

I think it's not possible to make an alias, since there is a whitespace in `fc -W`.

So I tried making a function, something like this:

```
# Make sure to never invoke fc -W
fc(){
    for x; do
        if [[ "${x}" == -W ]]; then
            echo "I'm sorry Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
            return
        fi
    done
    fc "${@}"
}
```

However, now the call `fc "${@}"` calls itself, and I get infinite recursion. Typically I would avoid this by using e.g. `/usr/bin/fc`, instead of `fc`, however:

```
$ type fc
> fc is a shell builtin
```

How can I avoid the infinite recursion in this case? Or is there a better way to disable one flag of a command?

Comment: I’m confused by the combination of zsh and bash functions tags.

Comment: Related: [How to specifically run a shell builtin command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362227/how-to-specifically-run-a-shell-builtin-command)

Comment: I wasn't clear at the beginning, sorry about that, but this is a pure `zsh` question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `builtin`:

```
builtin fc "$@"
```

This will ensure that the built-in `fc` command is called.

---

Style: The diagnostic message should go to the standard error stream and the function should return a non-zero status when failing:

```
echo 'Sorry, can not do that' >&2
return 1
```

Comment: If I type `command fc` in `zsh`, I get: `zsh: command not found: fc`.

Comment: @pfnuesel Ah, it's `zsh`. Use `builtin` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can override a built-in command or an external command or a function with an alias. While the alias is executing, an alias with the same name won't be expanded. Thus, if the expansion of the alias uses the name of the alias, this calls the built-in or external command or function of the same name. This means you can use an alias in a simple way to pass extra options to a command. But you can't do much more, due to the way alias expansion works — it's a simple substitution of words, without evaluation.

You can override a built-in command or an external command with a function. The fact that a function by a certain name is currently executing does not affect the execution, and in particular does not affect the meaning of the function name: it keeps referring to the function. Recursive functions aren't common in shell programming, but there's no rule against them.

In POSIX shells, you can force a name to refer to a built-in or external command by putting `command` before the call. In other words, `command` bypasses aliases and functions. In zsh, `command` forces a call to an external command (unless the option `posix_builtins` is set), i.e. it bypasses builtins as well. To force the execution of a builtin in zsh, use the `builtin` builtin.

This leads to one solution: in your wrapper function, call `builtin fc` instead of `fc`.

However, this is not necessarily the best solution in your case, because your function will be invoked everywhere, including calls to `fc` from other functions. When you override built-in behavior, I recommend sticking to an alias. An alias only applies to what you type at the command line or load with `.` (a.k.a. `source`), not to functions loaded with `autoload -U` (which is the recommended way to autoload a function). So define an `fc` alias that calls your wrapper function, and give your wrapper function a different name.

```
fc_wrapper () {
    for x; do
        if [[ "${x}" == -*W* ]]; then
            echo >&2 "I'm sorry Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that."
            return 1
        fi
    done
    \fc "${@}"
}
alias fc=fc_wrapper
```

I put `\fc` instead of `fc` in the function definition. This isn't necessary when loading the definition from `.zshrc` before the alias definition, but it is necessary, for example, if you edit or reload the function definition during your interactive session. I made a few minor improvements to the function as well:

- Print the error message on standard error.
- If you aren't doing the job, return an error status.
- Also catch cases such as `fc -WI`. This isn't fully robust, since it will also catch a call such as `fc -R -- -W` (reading history from a file called `-W`), but it's good enough for this use case.